# Hide directory name from URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I just want to hide the dir name from URL.

**From**: `example.com/dirname/somepage`
**To**: `example.com/somepage`

That code doesn't work for me, I have probably made some mistakes

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule    /  /dir/$1    [L]
```

I have already this in .htaccess (to hide php extension)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should be your complete .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+dirname/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!^dirname/)^(.*)$ /dirname/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: That is most common problem. For css, js, images etc make sure to use absolute paths starting with `/` or `http://`

Comment: Tried both. Not working and I really dont know why. I am sure the paths are valid.

Comment: If CSS path starts with `http://` it will be loaded no matter what URL scheme is used. Look the Firbug console see which URL is generating 404.

Comment: This is exactly what i have: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mydomain.com/css/main.css">` And it fails to load even my css file is exactly there. Same path without changing .htaccess works perfect. So i guess there is a problem with the rewrite rule.

Comment: It works, thank you! No need to change any path at all. Two minor problems I have 1)I have my contact form in a dir ("/contact") with an index.php controller and that URL stays the same. Do you have any idea?
2)What about the old URLs? They yet exist, I dont know if that is OK lets say for search engines (duplcate content)?

Comment: I can suggest a new rule to transalte old URL's to new one. Didn't understand the other form related question.

Comment: My contact form lives in a dir named "contact": mydomain.com/dir/contact/(form handling files here) 
Before rewrite I had the URL mydomain.com/dir/contact, and it yet remains like so

Comment: Ok that's it! Man, I really appreciate the time you spent to help me. Thanks a lot and keep up the good work.

Comment: Wow thank you. Took me hours just to get to this awesome solution.