# How can I hide folder name from URL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I have a website with the root folder 'www', but I put all php files including index.php in a sub-folder of root.
I wrote myself a .htaccess file to redirect, so if I input `www.test.com`, it will jump to `www.test.com/folder` and display the `index.php`.

Below it's my `.htaccess` which I put in the root.

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^folder2 - [L] 
 #ignore folder2 in which I put important files, but no works for the website
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder(.*)
 RewriteRule (.*) /folder/$1
```

Right now, I want to change the .htaccess file to reach these goals:

1. When I input `www.test.com`, jump to `www.test.com/folder` as usual, but display the url without **folder**.
2. All the pages in folder will display the url without folder name.
   Such as

   `www.test.com/shop/page1` -> `www.test.com/page1`

I searched some of the scripts, but none of them works.

Comment: Check this out... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361419/hide-directory-name-from-url

Comment: How is `/shop/` related to `/folder/`? Are they same?

Answer (score 6):

I've found this related question which answers to your problem. The snippet from the answer is (note: it's adjusted to your needs):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+folder/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!^folder/)^(.*)$ /folder/$1 [L,NC]
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18361995/3673491

Comment: I should replace this file with my .htaccess in the root, am I right? The sites only jump to the folder, but url still be 'www.test.com/folder'.

Comment: Note that I just updated the code with the answer from @NinjaCat suggestion, again adapted to your needs. Check it out and tell me if it's working properly now. I've made a simple local test here and it worked.

Note that you need to change wherever you see `folder` with the actual name you want to give to that folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?$ /folder/ [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your current rules. You can just make a slight adjustment.

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 #ignore folder2 in which I put important files, but no works for the website
 RewriteRule ^folder2/? - [L] 

 RewriteRule ^/?$ /folder/ [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1 [L]
```

Comment: It's not working. The website does not even show the index.php page any more.

Comment: It's still not jumping. Should I put this file in the folder or just keep it in the root?

Comment: What do you mean **not jumping**? I don't understand what you mean by that. What are you typing in the browser and what do you expect to happen? Start there.