# Remove 'storage' from Laravel image url

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I have uploaded one image to server, everything is set up correctly except I need to add `storage` in the URL to access images from public directory of Laravel.

https://example.com/a/xyz.png - NOT ACCESSIBLE

https://example.com/storage/a/xyz.png - ACCESSIBLE

But in local the URL without storage is accessible.

**NGINX**

```
root /var/www/example.in/live/public/;
index index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
server_name example.in www.example.in;
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
}
```

This is not the issue where I need to hide storage word from the URL. My problem the URL of image should work without the storage word by default. It is not working. The same code on my local machine which is managed by valet, is working fine without storage keyword

Comment: change it on htaccess

Comment: I am on nginx. What can be added for it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Show us your code.  Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I hide folder name from URL using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30194198/how-can-i-hide-folder-name-from-url-using-htaccess)

Comment: This migth be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30194198/how-can-i-hide-folder-name-from-url-using-htaccess . Because this can be archived using htaccess (htaccess is njot depending on apache or nginx; its working on both)

Comment: Do you have directory `public/a/`?

Comment: @Tpojka no, but the file is saved in public/storage/a/

Comment: "URL of image should work without the storage word by default" <- this is false. 
Going to give you one answer how to achieve it.

Comment: @Tpojka ok I think my local system is somehow redirecting user to correct path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thing is that with executing command `php artisan storage:link` it's supposed to be on that location (i.e. `public_path('storage')`). It's default behaviour. You can link manually to wanted location as:

```
ln -s /absolute/path/to/project_root/storage/app/public /absolute/path/to/project_root/public/wanted-name-of-directory
```

or to extend native command with custom one. For latter solution, follow logic from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50639622/set-default-host-value-for-php-artisan-serve/50640514#50640514). It should be like:

1. `php artisan make:command CustomStorageLinkCommand`
2. Then delete all from newly created file and use this code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\StorageLinkCommand;

class CustomStorageLinkCommand extends StorageLinkCommand
{
    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Create a symbolic link from "public/a" to "storage/app/public"';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        if (file_exists(public_path('a'))) {
            return $this->error('The "public/a" directory already exists.');
        }
        $this->laravel->make('files')->link(
            storage_path('app/public'), public_path('a')
        );
        $this->info('The [public/a] directory has been linked.');
    }
}
```

3. Execute `php artisan storage:link` command

Comment: thanks for the answer but it ain't the correct solution. In my location I am having same directory structure `public/storage/a/` but it is working `localhost/a/xyz.img`. Also, directory `a` is just for example there will be `n` directory like `a` with different name. The ideal location is inside the storage folder of public. I don't understant how it is working on local machine but not on server.

Comment: So, final conclusion is storage comes in URL by default. My local system valet was somehow manipulating the URL without the storage word in it.