# Laravel 5.7 upload to public folder doesnt' work

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to upload images to the `storage/app/public/` folder that is linked to the public folder from Laravel. My `filesystems.php` is configured this way:

```
'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'public')
//rest of the code
        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

And at my controller, I upload the image:

```
$file = $request->hasFile('imagem');
$file = $request->file('imagem')->isValid();

$upload = $request->imagem->store('instituicoes');
```

I want the file to be uploaded to this path `storage/app/public/instituicoes` but when I use this code Laravel creates the 'instituicoes' folder at the `storage/app` folder, not at the `storage/app/public/` that I defined as storage path.
[image: Laravel Folders]

Comment: Have you linked your storage folder by `php artisan storage:link` ?!

Comment: Couple days ago someone else wanted to remove `storage` word from URL. I offered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54588997/remove-storage-from-laravel-image-url/54589932#54589932) solution, but I think it could give you idea what you need to do to set other location than `storage/app/public` for linking.

Comment: I used `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: What's the value of your `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER` environment variable? If it's not `public`, then you're not storing to the public disk by default

Comment: It's public. It's the first line of code I showed at the question.

Comment: Have you tried `php artisan config:clear` to reset any cached config values?

Comment: I did that, also stopped the developement server and started it again but nothing changed. I just found something interesting. I can't retrieve any enviroment variable with `env()` helper, it always returns null. I tried to retrieve even basic database enviroment variables like `dd(env('DB_HOST'))` and laravel returns me null. But the system is all working fine, I just can't retrieve enviroment variables like the `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER`

Comment: That sounds a *lot* like your config is still cached, which would partly explain why changing `filesystems.php` has no effect. However, if you ran `config:clear` and nothing changed maybe it's a filesystem permissions issue? Check and make sure `bootstrap/cache/config.php` does *not* exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your default disk is using the `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER` environment variable, make sure that the value of the variable is set to `public` as your default disk. It looks like it might be using your `local` disk instead.

You could also try changing this:

```php
$upload = $request->imagem->store('instituicoes');
```

to this:

```php
$upload = $request->imagem->store('instituicoes', 'public');
```

to force using the `public` disk instead of whatever the default is.

Comment: The FILESYSTEM_DRIVER is set to public as I show in the first line of code of the question. I tried this: $upload = $request->imagem->store('instituicoes', 'public'); but the image wasn't stored wasn't stored at the pulblic, neither at the app/instituicoes as it was happening.

Comment: @NatanRochaBatista The first line actually does *not* show the value. The second parameter of `env()` is the *default* value, which is only used when the environment variable is not set anywhere (like in your `.env` file). It's impossible to tell from your code if the value has been set anywhere.

Comment: This 'FILESYSTEM_DRIVER' isn't set anywhere else in the code, not even at the .env file. I just searched for it and the only file where this variable is set is the filesystems.php. I tried to `dd(env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER')` to find the variable value and it returned null.

Comment: @NatanRochaBatista What does `Storage::disk('public')->path('')` return?

Comment: @NatanRochaBatista also, have you double checked that your server has write permissions in the public folder? If you tried `->store('instituicoes', 'public')` and it didn't save in *either* folder, then it sounds like your server doesn't have write permissions

Comment: Thank you so much for the help Travis. I woke up today, turned on my laptop and it was working perfectly. I have no idea why, as I told you, a cleared the cache one thousand times. But it's working right now.

Answer (score 0):

From https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem

The public disk is intended for files that are going to be publicly accessible. By default, the  public disk uses the local driver and stores these files in storage/app/public. To make them accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic link from public/storage to  storage/app/public.

To create the symbolic link, you may use the storage:link Artisan command:

php artisan storage:link

Comment: It's linked. What is happening is that the files are not being uploaded to `storage/app/public` as I described in the question.