# Hide directory name in site URL for Index, Posts and Pages

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I tried different solutions for hidding a directory URL in my wordpress site. For example, I follow the next solution and (in my case) doesn´t work:

[Hide directory name from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361419/hide-directory-name-from-url)

Also I tried this from Wordpress Support site (Method II):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

I have installed wordpress in (for example: mysite.com/dirname) and make a rule in hosting's cpanel that allow me to access the site just typing mysite.com. But as I said before, I just want to hide the /dirname in site URL for index, post and pages mostly.

All help that you can provide me is much apreciated. Thanks and sorry for my English.

Regards.

My .htaccess file located on /dirname folder have the following code (the first code lines are related to a security plugin, the important lines are on the bottom from #BEGIN WP to #END WP):

```
# BEGIN All In One WP Security
#AIOWPS_BASIC_HTACCESS_RULES_START
<Files .htaccess>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
ServerSignature Off
LimitRequestBody 10240000
<Files wp-config.php>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
#AIOWPS_BASIC_HTACCESS_RULES_END
#AIOWPS_DEBUG_LOG_BLOCK_HTACCESS_RULES_START
<Files debug.log>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
#AIOWPS_DEBUG_LOG_BLOCK_HTACCESS_RULES_END
# END All In One WP Security

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dirname
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /dirname/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

The *best* solution to this problem is to simply move everything from /dirname up one directory so that you don't have to rewrite anything at all.

The next best solution is to remove everything between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" and replace it with:

```
FallbackResource /dirname/index.php
```

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource for further discussion of `FallbackResource`.

Comment: Hi, I understand, but I don't know if I can do that because I have other sites in construction in the same hosting, and I want to put those sites in a folder separately like this one. The "up" folder is public_html precisely. At least, that my hosting provider allow me through cpanel add other public_html folders that don't interfiere between each one of them. I will try the second best solution in the meantime. Thanks!.