# htaccess RewriteRule and RewriteBase

Tags: regex, .htaccess, regex-lookarounds

i want hide a part of url
current url: 
https://dev.karmagroup.com/karmamomentsnew/karma-postcards/

what i aim for is
https://dev.karmagroup.com/karma-postcards/

with the current .htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /karmamomentsnew/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /karmamomentsnew/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

i tried to change the .htaccess like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /karmamomentsnew/(.+)$ $1 [L,NC,R]
</IfModule>
```

and it goes wrong surely, haha.. can somebody help me please. thank you before.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this related question which answers your problem. The snippet from the answer is (note that it's adjusted to your needs)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!^karmamomentsnew/)^(.*)$ /karmamomentsnew/$1 [L,NC]
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18361995/5675325